# is there any way to use domain file in subdomain to?

Tags: php, path

i have a site which has a subdomain, for example domian.com and forum.domain.com.
in my domain.com i have inc folder which contain my initialize.php and config.php my classes and functions in it. i just include initialize.php in each php page and other pages included in initialize.php like config.php
in config.php i define

```
define("BASE_URL","/");
define("ROOT_PATH",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/")
```

now when I include initialize in subdomain it dosen't work because ROOT_PATH assumed as subdomain. in this situation what sholud I do? how can I use files that are in domian.com root in subdomain?
should I copy all off them in subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a simple trick like following,

```
<?php
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .  '/../inc/header.php';
```

I recommend you to read the following tutorial
https://developer.hyvor.com/php/including-files-in-root-with-subdomain.php